# Como adicionar remover e/ou adicionar classe de um elemento quando clicado?

Tags: javascript, html

CODIGO HTML

Comunidade Goulart | Aqui compartilhamos conhecimento

```
<header>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <nav>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Inicio</a>
            <a href="#">Projetos</a>
            <a href="#">Sobre</a>
            <a href="#">Comunidade</a>
            <a id="btn__portfolio_color" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
    </nav>
</header>

<main>
    <section id="s__initial" class="width">
        <article id="s__left">
            <a class="c__twitch" href="#"><span>TWITCH</span></a>
            <a class="c__youtube" href="#"><span>YOUTUBE</span></a>
            <a class="c__discord" href="#"><span>DISCORD</span></a>
            <a class="c__github" href="#"><span>GITHUB</span></a>
            <a class="c__instagram" href="#"><span>INSTAGRAM</span></a>
        </article>
        <article id="s__right">
            <div class="barra" id="b__laranja">
                <h1>LARANJA</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="barra" id="b__roxa">
                <div id="c__discord">
                    <h1>DISCORD</h1>
                        <a href="#">
                            <h3>COMUNIDADE GOULART</h3>
                            <p>Leia nossas regras antes de participar para evitar punições</p>
                            <p>Salas</p>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="barra" id="b__verdinha"></div>
            <div class="barra" id="b__verde"></div>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>

<footer>
    <div id="f__1"></div>
    <div id="f__2"><p>Criador por Rafael Goulart 2022</p></div>
</footer>

<!-- CODIGO JAVASCRIPT -->
<!-- Script usado para add e remover class dos elementos com a class "barra" quando clicados.-->
<script>
    const barra = document.getElementsByClassName('barra');

    barra[0].addEventListener("click", removerClass0);
    barra[1].addEventListener("click", removerClass1);
    barra[2].addEventListener("click", removerClass2);
    barra[3].addEventListener("click", removerClass3);

    function removerClass0(){
        barra[0].classList.add('principal');
        barra[1].classList.remove('principal');
        barra[2].classList.remove('principal');
        barra[3].classList.remove('principal');
    }
    function removerClass1(){
        barra[0].classList.remove('principal');
        barra[1].classList.add('principal');
        barra[2].classList.remove('principal');
        barra[3].classList.remove('principal');
    }
    function removerClass2(){
        barra[0].classList.remove('principal');
        barra[1].classList.remove('principal');
        barra[2].classList.add('principal');
        barra[3].classList.remove('principal');
    }
    function removerClass3(){
        barra[0].classList.remove('principal');
        barra[1].classList.remove('principal');
        barra[2].classList.remove('principal');
        barra[3].classList.add('principal');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Tenho pouco conhecimento sobre Javascript, esse codigo esta funcionando normal mais gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de deixa-lo mais curto e otimizado.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Sem ter o HTML como referência e sem saber o objetivo do código fica difícil fazer uma análise.

Comment: Tem, mas soluções para problemas individuais não é bem o foco do site. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Agora, se for pra palpitar no código, a solução mais simples é um "for" iterando de 1 a 4, e fazer if i = n add principal else remove principal, ai esse loop atende todas as situações. Aí você usa removerClass[i] em vez de mudar o nome da variável (class0 fica class[0] etc) - Seria algo como `function algumacoisaClass(n)` para todos os casos. Da mesma forma, um loop só faria o addEventListener

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Acredito que seja algo assim:

```js
let barra = document.querySelectorAll(".barra");

barra.forEach((item)=>{

    
    item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      
        barra.forEach((i) => {
            if(i != this){

                i.classList.remove("principal");
            }
        });

      this.classList.toggle("principal");
      
    })
  });
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente esse codigo, fiquei impressionado o quanto fico resumido o codigo. Só tem um problema, como eu estou usando isso para abrir um laque de "cartas" eu queria que quando uma "div recebesse a tag (principal) as demais perdecem.

Comment: Coloca minha pergunta como a certa. Entendi oq você quer!! Acho que vc deve tirar as classes "principal" de todas antes. Deixa sem nada. Acredito que o codigo que coloquei vai funcionar!

Comment: Seu codigo funcionou, mais se eu clico na DIV_1 e DIV_2 ele adiciona nas 2 e isso esta bugando o layout que projetei, eu queria que ao clicar na DIV_2 ele removesse a classe da DIV_1 e vice-versa.

Se poder ajustar o codigo eu agradeço pois não sei como fazer isso, de qualquer forma obrigado por comentar.

Comment: Pronto, modifiquei a resposta. Testa ai!

Comment: Funcionou igual aquele que eu fiz, so que esse esta bem melhor pois esta resumido, quando um recebe a class o outro perde, porem para remover de todos tenho que dar F5 na pagina.

Para explicar melhor, tenho 4 DIV com a CLASS .BARRA, quando eu clico na BARRA 1 ele adiciona a class principal e faz ele se expandir, se eu clico na DIV 2 ele remove a class da DIV 1 e adiciona na DIV 2 fazendo ele se expandir, porem se eu clico na mesma DIV para remover a class e deixar fechado ele nao remove a class

Comment: Agora acho que vai dar certo srrsrs

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo., tenho certeza que esse codigo vai ajudar outras pessoas também. Vou estudar esse codigo para aprender